# Загрузка данных в БД django

Tags: python, django

Всем привет. Мне нужно загрузить данные из файла по команде в БД. Подскажите, пожалуйста как правильно.

Модели

```
class Question(models.Model):
question_text = models.CharField(verbose_name='Вопрос', max_length=250)
choice = models.ManyToManyField('Choice')

class Choice(models.Model):
choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
next_question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                  related_name='linked_choice')
```

В файле есть вопросы и варианты ответов. Вью подает вопрос и варианты ответов из бд пользователю  на выбор.  Мне нужно заполнить эти модели данными.
Написал команду, questions - список кортежей, кортеж из двух элементов состоит: вопрос и словарь с вариантами.

```
 def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
    questions = self.csv_reader(data)

    for question in questions:
        answers = set(question[1].keys())

        for option in answers:
            Question.objects.create(question_text=question[0],
                                    choice=Choice.objects.create(
                                        choice_text=option))

TypeError: Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use choice.set() instead.
```

Ошибку выдает.
Еще сложность в том, что довольно сложная структура получается, если через админку попытаться добавить вопросы, то нужно ввести вопрос, затем создать вариант ответа, кот требует ввести след вопрос(next_question), кот требует снова ввести вопрос вариант ответа итд

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Он же тебе пишет, что для отношений `ManyToMany`  нужно отдельно заносить с помощью метода `set`
Вообще по твоим циклам получается, что для каждого варианта ответа ты создаешь свой отдельный вопрос.

```
for question in questions:
    question_obj = Question.objects.create(question_text=question[0])
    answers = []
    for option in question[1].keys():
        answers.append(Choice.objects.create(choice_text=option))
    question_obj.choice.set(answers)
```

Судя по файлу загрузки, если ты сделаешь `inline` в админке, то вводить будет достаточно удобно.

Comment: Спасибо большое